# Am I not allowed to pass props from outside of the map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building an app with React, and getting a TypeError that my function doesn't exist. My function starts in here where I pass it to a child component:

```
class InvoiceScreen extends Component {

state = {
    numberOfInvoices: InvoiceData.length,
    currentDisplay: <InvoiceList
                        openInvoice={this.openInvoice}
                    />
};

checkInvoiceLength = () => {
    var isEmpty = document.getElementById("InvoiceList").innerHTML === "";
    if (isEmpty == false) {
        this.setState({display: "untoggled"})
    }
    else if (isEmpty == true) {
        this.setState({hasInvoices: "toggled"})
    }
}

openInvoice = (int) => {
    this.setState({currentDisplay:
        <InvoiceDetails 
            idNumber={InvoiceData[int].id}
            description={InvoiceData[int].description}
            street={InvoiceData[int].senderAddress.street}
            city={InvoiceData[int].senderAddress.city}
            postCode={InvoiceData[int].senderAddress.postCode}
            country={InvoiceData[int].senderAddress.country}
            createdAt={InvoiceData[int].createdAt}
            paymentDue={InvoiceData[int].paymentDue}
            clientStreet={InvoiceData[int].clientAddress.street}
            clientCity={InvoiceData[int].clientAddress.city}
            clientPostCode={InvoiceData[int].clientAddress.postCode}
            clientCountry={InvoiceData[int].clientAddress.country}
            clientEmail={InvoiceData[int].clientEmail}
            items={InvoiceData[int].items}
            total={InvoiceData[int].total}
    />})
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="InvoiceScreen">
            <IconBar />
            <div className="DisplayArea">
                {this.state.currentDisplay}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Then from this component, I pass it down to multiple components created through the map function

```
class InvoiceList extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}
render() {
    return(
        <div className="InvoiceListScreen">
            <InvoiceOptions numberOfInvoices={this.props.numberOfInvoices} />
            <div id="InvoiceList">
                {InvoiceData.map((invoice, index,) => 
                    <InvoiceBar
                        openInvoice={this.props.openInvoice}
                        key={index}
                        position={index} 
                        idNumber={invoice.id}
                        clientName={invoice.clientName}
                        paymentDue={invoice.paymentDue}
                        price={Formatter.format(invoice.total)}
                        status={invoice.status.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + invoice.status.slice(1).toLowerCase()}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

And then finally inside of the mapped components, I call it as an onClick

```
class InvoiceBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="InvoiceBar" onClick={() => this.props.openInvoice(this.props.position)}>
                <h4 className="idNumber"><span className="Hashtag">#</span>{this.props.idNumber}</h4>
                <p className="clientName">{this.props.clientName}</p>
                <div className="DueAndPrice">
                    <p className="paymentDue">Due {this.props.paymentDue}</p>
                    <h3 className="price">{this.props.price}</h3>
                </div>
                <PaymentStatus status={this.props.status} />
            </div>
        )
    }    
}
```

And then like I said, I'm given a TypeError saying that it isn't a function. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the function being passed as props from outside of the map function in the second component. Can someone please enlighten me on what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have `this.openInvoice` in `InvoiceScreen`? I don't see it in the code

Comment: You need to create the function body in `InvoiceScreen`

Comment: Try to log the value of `openInvoice` prop in `InvoiceList` component's `render` method and see what is logged on the console.

Comment: I logged it to the console, and it says 'undefined'. I also added the whole first component.

Comment: Storing React components/JSX in state is anti-pattern, have you considered writing normal React components that store only *data* in state and render JSX derived from that state? Seems you really want to either render the list or a specific `InvoiceBar` by index. Could help unwrangle possible stale state/enclosures/etc... I suspect that `this.openInvoice` simply isn't defined yet in the constructor.

Comment: I didn't realize it was a bad practice. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that class fields run *in order* in which they're listed. They're not like normal methods, which get defined on the prototype ahead of time. For a simplified version:

```
class InvoiceScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    openInvoice: this.openInvoice
  };
  openInvoice = () => {
    // some function
  }
```

desugars to:

```
class InvoiceScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      openInvoice: this.openInvoice
    };
    this.openInvoice = () => {
      // some function
    }
```

See the problem? You're defining `this.state` before you're defining `this.openInvoice`.

Easiest solution would be to move the definition of `this.state` to the bottom:

```
class InvoiceScreen extends Component {
  // PUT ALL OTHER METHOD DEFINITIONS HERE

  // then just before the end of the component:
  state = {
    numberOfInvoices: InvoiceData.length,
    currentDisplay: <InvoiceList
                        openInvoice={this.openInvoice}
                    />
  };
}
```

That said, putting a React component into state is really, really weird. Consider a different approach if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that was an odd way of doing it, I'll try something else.